# Warning: SQLite3::query(): near "ALTER": syntax error

Tags: php, sqlite3

Warning: SQLite3::query(): near "ALTER": syntax error in C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\app\api.php on line 5

```
$db = new SQLite3('database.db');

// $db->exec('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, datetime INTEGER)');

$db->query('ALTER TABLE posts ALTER COLUMN datetime TEXT');
```

Подскажите что не так в коде и как изменить тип поля?

у `datetime` тип `INTEGER`, хочу заменить на `TEXT`

Answer (score 1):

Низя так делать. SQLite не поддерживает смену типа столбца https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

Comment: Вот блин, вчера еще узнал что файл блокируется если в него что то пишется или меняется. Зря связался с такой базой, одни проблемы от нее и ограничения

Comment: И даже удалить колонку нельзя `Warning: SQLite3::exec(): near "DROP": syntax error`